# How to display label on side of doughnut in chart js

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to get labels on side of my doughnut chart. I am using chart Js, any help would be great.

On the link bellow: is an example of how i want the chart to look like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRDvo.png

Answer (score 0):

According to the chart.js [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#data-structure) that is not possible.

But take a look at [chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels) plugin. Which can be used to display labels on side of doughnut.